# SwiftUI 4 NavigationLink is invoking the link twice

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using the new `NavigationLink` in iOS 16 and hitting a problem where the target of the `.navigationDestination` is being called twice. Example code:

```
struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { number in
                        NavigationLink(value: number) {
                            Text("\(number)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { value in
                SubView(model: Model(value: value))
            }
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Int
                
    init(value: Int) {
        print("Init for value \(value)")
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.value)")
    }
}
```

When I touch one of the numbers in the `Content` view the `init` message in the model is shown twice, indicating that the class has been instantiated more than once. This is not a problem in a trivial example like this, but in my app the model does a network fetch and calculation so this is being done twice, which is more of an issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate or similar [Swift UI @FocusState triggering NavigationLink Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73777958/swift-ui-focusstate-triggering-navigationlink-twice)

Comment: Looks like it is - that didn't come up in my search. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is caused by ObservableObject. It needs to store it's state. I think it's better to use StateObject. Please try that one for SubView. :)

```
struct SubView: View {
    @StateObject private var model: Model

    init(value: Int) {
        self._model = StateObject(wrappedValue: Model(value: value))
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: StateObject is probably better than ObservedObject in this case, but Apple specifically say you should not use the StateObject init function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/init(wrappedvalue:)